# How to showing a view in a marquee?

Tags: views

I have a view and I am going to show 5 last contents in a marquee at the top of page, and I want to show it in one line I mean no `<br/>`

How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the `<marquee>` implement its effect using jQuery, go to this [link](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Text-Scrolling-Plugin-for-jQuery-Marquee/) or [this one](http://www.ondeweb.in/marquee-with-css-and-jquery/)  download the files and it moves the text like marquee.

If your view name is `V1` create a block and replace the text with this command

```
<?php views_embed_view("V1","block");?>
```

also you need to select the last five items in views UI.